# jQuery CSS not working but Animate is

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Has anyone ever encountered a situation where this code doesn't work:

```
$('#whatever').css({
  left:'+=7px'
});
```

But this code does:

```
$('#whatever').animate({
  left:'+=7px'
}, 10);
```

The element Styles are as follows:

```
#whatever {
  position: relative;
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

I can't seem to get it to work...  Any ideas?!

Comment: I was to move it `7px`... left, right, top or bottom... but without using `animate()` or setting that element to `absolute`

Comment: @Frédéric: ["As of jQuery 1.6, .css() accepts relative values similar to .animate(). Relative values are a string starting with += or -= to increment or decrement the current value."](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: @mu, you're absolutely right, I forgot about that new feature. Thanks for the heads-up :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#whatever').css({
  left:'+=7'
});
```

remove 'px' after 7

and check for your jQuery version

As of jQuery **1.6** .css() accepts relative values

Comment: You need the CSS value as a string don't you?

Comment: Thank you! The issue was that our CDN has an old version of jQuery - just updated it. Thanks!

Comment: @Marco: from source code // convert relative number strings (+= or -=) to relative numbers. #7345
   value = ( +( ret[1] + 1) * +ret[2] ) + parseFloat( jQuery.css( elem, name ) );
    // Fixes bug #9237
    type = "number";
   }

   
   // If a number was passed in, add 'px' to the (except for certain CSS properties)
   if ( type === "number" && !jQuery.cssNumber[ origName ] ) {
    value += "px";
   }

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#whatever').css( "left","+=7" )
```

See http://api.jquery.com/css/ :)

Comment: Using a different way to set the same style doesn't help, as relative values doesn't work with CSS.

Comment: @Marco: Relative values for `.css` only came in with 1.6 so I guess a lot of people don't know about it yet.

Comment: Oh ok.. Didn't even know it was that new :/

Comment: Looks like everyone gets to learn something new today then :)